# Possible to use NSView subclass in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview

I have an `NSView` subclass that I'd like to use in an `NSTableView`. Normally of course I'd use a `NSTableCellView` subclass but this view will be used elsewhere.

Possible?

Comment: What's the point of doing this? You custom view can be subview of the NSTableCellView??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `NSView` subclass to inherit from `NSTableCellView` instead of `NSView`, since `NSTableCellView` also inherits from `NSView` too.

Comment: I appreciate Ken's answer but this was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement that the cell view used for a view-based table view be an `NSTableCellView` or subclass. It's perfectly OK to use an instance of some other view object. For example, an `NSTextField` works out of the box.

Your table view delegate's `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method can configure the view as appropriate for the row. Or, your view can implement an `objectValue` property (with `-setObjectValue:` setter). In this case, the table view will forward whatever object value your data source returns from its `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method to your view's `objectValue` property.

Also, if your view class has `textField` or `imageView` properties (like `NSTableCellView` does), then those will be treated specially in certain cases. For example, the text field will be the accessibility string for the cell.

Basically, all of the behaviors of `NSTableCellView` are generalizable. It's not that the class is treated particularly specially by the framework. It's that it provides the appropriate properties and methods and any view with those same properties and methods could replicate its behavior.