# Subclass NSView instead of NSTableCellView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

This question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186051/possible-to-use-nsview-subclass-in-nstableview) question.

I am working on Cocoa App, where I am populating a table using `Cocoa Bindings`.

I am  subclassing NSView instead of NSTableCellView

As per [NSTableCellView Class Referenence](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableCellView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009510-CH1-SW4)

> If you use your own custom view cells that are not based on
>   NSTableCellView you should implement this property(objectValue) in order to be able
>   to receive changes to cell values.

Also

> swift
>   **var objectValue: AnyObject?**
>   The objectValue is automatically set by the table when using bindings or is th...

---

This is my class implementation, which I will be using as cell in TableView

```
class TestView : NSView {
    var objectValue: AnyObject?

    init(nameA: String, nameB: String) {
        super.init(frame: NSMakeRect(3, 3, 300, 40))

        objectValue = nameA
        let firstName = MyTextField(location: NSMakePoint(10, 10), stringVal: nameA)
        self.addSubview(firstName)

        let secondName = MyTextField(location: NSMakePoint(250, 10), stringVal: nameB)
        self.addSubview(secondName)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

---

Although having declared the `objectValue` in TestClass, I am still not able to bind the object value from IB

Answer (score 2):

Custom views and objects don't get custom property bindings in IB. YOU HAVE TO SET UP BINDINGS IN CODE.

You also need to ensure your class does all the fun stuff required to enable bindings.